# NSKeyedArchiver - archiving a dictionary that uses an enum as the key

Tags: ios, swift

I want to archive a dictionary that uses a simple enum as the key:

```
 public enum DaysOfWeek: Int, Codable {
    case Sunday = 1
    case Monday
    case Tuesday
    case Wednesday
    case Thursday
    case Friday
    case Saturday
}
```

and the dictionary is:

```
var myDict: Dictionary<DaysOfWeek, [SomeDataType]>
```

I've tried encoding like this:

```
        aCoder.encode(myDict, forKey: "MyKey")
```

but this crashes with an anonymous NSException error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

(lldb) bt
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x0000000183b75348 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
    frame #1: 0x0000000183c89344 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 396
    frame #2: 0x0000000183ae4fb8 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 140
    frame #3: 0x0000000183284068 libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 132
    frame #4: 0x0000000183284210 libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 304
    frame #5: 0x00000001832ac810 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 124
    frame #6: 0x000000018329c54c libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
    frame #7: 0x000000018329c158 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 144
    frame #8: 0x00000001832ac6e8 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 44
    frame #9: 0x0000000183f24024 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 544
    frame #10: 0x0000000185dbbf84 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 100
    frame #11: 0x000000018d4f82f4 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 208
  * frame #12: 0x00000001026fbe98 CycleTrainer`main at AppDelegate.swift:18
    frame #13: 0x0000000183a4656c libdyld.dylib`start + 4

What am I missing???

Comment: " an anonymous NSException error." Show us the whole error then?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the Question with the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the `rawValue` of the enum instead? Thus, you'll be able to encode the dictionary.

```
var myDict: [Int: SomeDataType] = [:]
myDict[DaysOfWeek.Tuesday.rawValue] = SomeDataType() // Assign some encodable data type.
```